# unexpected '&#x' appearing in XSL output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to use a template to replace a string 'REPORT_BLANK' with a default value "". It seems to be working for the 'Status' attribute (within the xsl output), however, for the 'PayGroup' attirbute I am getting unexpected output containing '&#x' characters and data from elements which I do not require. Please help this newbie.

XML source:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<DATA_DS>
    <G_1>
        <PAYROLL_ACTION_ID>5103</PAYROLL_ACTION_ID>
        <G_2>
            <FILE_FRAGMENT>
                <PayrollInterface>
                    <REP_CATEGORY_NAME>HMLR ePayfact GIF Interface 1</REP_CATEGORY_NAME>
                    <parameters>
                        <RequestID>300000016822367</RequestID>
                        <FLOW_NAME>04102017-11:26</FLOW_NAME>
                        <LegislativeDataGroupID>300000001404188</LegislativeDataGroupID>
                        <EffectiveDate>2017-10-04</EffectiveDate>
                        <StartDate>2017-10-04</StartDate>
                        <ReportCategoryID>300000016773109</ReportCategoryID>
                        <action_parameter_group_id>300000000174069</action_parameter_group_id>
                        <ChangesOnly>N</ChangesOnly>
                        <PayrollName>300000001632050</PayrollName>
                        <PayrollPeriod/>
                        <SuppressZeroBalance/>
                    </parameters>
                    <InterfaceData>
                        <OBJECT_ACTION_ID>18527</OBJECT_ACTION_ID>
                        <Employee>
                            <Employee>
                                <EmployeeBasic>
                                    <EmployeeNo>50120</EmployeeNo>
                                </EmployeeBasic>
                            </Employee>
                        </Employee>
                        <EELocation>
                            <EELocation_Employment>
                                <EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EELocation_Assignment>
                                        <EELocation_Rec>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000016784341</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                        </EELocation_Rec>
                                    </EELocation_Assignment>
                                </EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                            </EELocation_Employment>
                        </EELocation>
                        <EEPSPayChange>
                            <EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                                <EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                        <GradeStepRateValue_Record/>
                                        <EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000016784341</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                            <PersonLatestHireDate_Internal>2017-10-03T00:00:00.000Z</PersonLatestHireDate_Internal>
                                            <EffectiveDate>2017-10-03T00:00:00.000Z</EffectiveDate>
                                            <ChangeType>START</ChangeType>
                                            <GradeId/>
                                            <AssignmentCategory_Internal/>
                                            <GradeSubCode>REPORT_BLANK</GradeSubCode>
                                            <Salary_Internal/>
                                            <Salary_2_Internal>TOBEDERIVED</Salary_2_Internal>
                                            <AssignFullTimeHours_Internal>37</AssignFullTimeHours_Internal>
                                            <MaxOTRateType>N</MaxOTRateType>
                                            <FTE_Internal>1</FTE_Internal>
                                            <PayGroupId>06</PayGroupId>
                                            <PersonType_Internal>Permanent</PersonType_Internal>
                                            <Classification>01</Classification>
                                            <HoursPayable>37</HoursPayable>
                                            <WorkingPatternId>501</WorkingPatternId>
                                            <OSPSchemeNo>1</OSPSchemeNo>
                                            <MilestoneDate_Internal>TOBEDERIVED</MilestoneDate_Internal>
                                        </EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                    </EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                </EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                            </EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                        </EEPSPayChange>
                        <EEPSLocation>
                            <EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                                <EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                                    <EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                        <EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                            <PersonType_Internal>Permanent</PersonType_Internal>
                                            <PersonLatestHireDate_Internal>2017-10-03T00:00:00.000Z</PersonLatestHireDate_Internal>
                                            <EffectiveDate>2017-10-03T00:00:00.000Z</EffectiveDate>
                                            <DetachedDutyInd>N</DetachedDutyInd>
                                            <LedgerHeading>LD</LedgerHeading>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000016784341</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                        </EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                    </EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                </EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                            </EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                        </EEPSLocation>
                        <EEBankDetail/>
                        <EEPaymentElement/>
                    </InterfaceData>
                    <InterfaceData>
                        <OBJECT_ACTION_ID>18505</OBJECT_ACTION_ID>
                        <Employee>
                            <Employee>
                                <EmployeeBasic>
                                    <EmployeeNo>50061</EmployeeNo>
                                    <Status>REPORT_BLANK</Status>
                                    <PensElig>Y</PensElig>
                                </EmployeeBasic>
                                <EmployeeBasic_DateMarriageCeased>
                                    <PersonDetailsRecords>
                                        <PersonDetails>
                                            <PersonID_Internal>300000015958328</PersonID_Internal>
                                            <DateMarriageCeased/>
                                        </PersonDetails>
                                    </PersonDetailsRecords>
                                </EmployeeBasic_DateMarriageCeased>
                                <EmployeeTermination>
                                    <TerminationDetailsRecord>
                                        <TerminationDetails>
                                            <TerminationAction_Internal/>
                                            <TerminationStatus_Internal>REPORT_BLANK</TerminationStatus_Internal>
                                            <LeavingDate/>
                                            <ReasonForLeaving/>
                                            <PersonID_Internal>300000015958328</PersonID_Internal>
                                        </TerminationDetails>
                                    </TerminationDetailsRecord>
                                </EmployeeTermination>
                            </Employee>
                        </Employee>
                        <EELocation>
                            <EELocation_Employment>
                                <EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EELocation_Assignment>
                                        <EELocation_Rec>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000015958405</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                        </EELocation_Rec>
                                    </EELocation_Assignment>
                                </EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                            </EELocation_Employment>
                            <EELocation_Employment>
                                <EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EELocation_Assignment>
                                        <EELocation_Rec>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000016544638</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                        </EELocation_Rec>
                                    </EELocation_Assignment>
                                </EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                            </EELocation_Employment>
                        </EELocation>
                        <EEPSPayChange>
                            <EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                                <EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                        <GradeStepRateValue_Record>
                                            <GradeStepRateValue>
                                                <GradeStepRateValue_Record>
                                                    <AssgnID_Internal>300000015958405</AssgnID_Internal>
                                                    <GradeStepRateValue_Internal>49547</GradeStepRateValue_Internal>
                                                </GradeStepRateValue_Record>
                                            </GradeStepRateValue>
                                        </GradeStepRateValue_Record>
                                        <EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000015958405</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                            <PayGroupId>06</PayGroupId>
                                        </EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                    </EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                </EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                            </EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                            <EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                                <EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                        <GradeStepRateValue_Record/>
                                        <EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                            <PayGroupId>08</PayGroupId>
                                        </EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                    </EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                </EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                            </EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                        </EEPSPayChange>
                        <EEPSLocation>
                            <EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                                <EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                                    <EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                        <EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                            <PersonType_Internal>Permanent</PersonType_Internal>
                                        </EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                    </EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                </EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                            </EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                            <EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                                <EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                                    <EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                        <EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                            <PersonType_Internal>Permanent</PersonType_Internal>
                                        </EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                    </EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                </EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                            </EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                        </EEPSLocation>
                        <EEBankDetail/>
                        <EEPaymentElement/>
                    </InterfaceData>
                    <InterfaceData>
                        <OBJECT_ACTION_ID>18511</OBJECT_ACTION_ID>
                        <Employee>
                            <Employee>
                                <EmployeeBasic>
                                    <EmployeeNo>41356</EmployeeNo>
                                    <EffectiveDate>2017-10-04T00:00:00.000Z</EffectiveDate>
                                    <PensElig>Y</PensElig>
                                </EmployeeBasic>
                                <EmployeeBasic_DateMarriageCeased>
                                    <PersonDetailsRecords>
                                        <PersonDetails>
                                            <PersonID_Internal>300000015238875</PersonID_Internal>
                                            <DateMarriageCeased/>
                                        </PersonDetails>
                                    </PersonDetailsRecords>
                                </EmployeeBasic_DateMarriageCeased>
                                <EmployeeAddress/>
                                <EmployeeTermination>
                                    <TerminationDetailsRecord>
                                        <TerminationDetails>
                                            <TerminationAction_Internal/>
                                            <TerminationStatus_Internal>REPORT_BLANK</TerminationStatus_Internal>
                                            <LeavingDate/>
                                            <ReasonForLeaving/>
                                            <PersonID_Internal>300000015238875</PersonID_Internal>
                                        </TerminationDetails>
                                    </TerminationDetailsRecord>
                                </EmployeeTermination>
                            </Employee>
                        </Employee>
                        <EELocation>
                            <EELocation_Employment>
                                <EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EELocation_Assignment>
                                        <EELocation_Rec>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000015239345</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                        </EELocation_Rec>
                                    </EELocation_Assignment>
                                </EELocation_Assignment_Data>
                            </EELocation_Employment>
                        </EELocation>
                        <EEPSPayChange>
                            <EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                                <EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                                    <EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                        <GradeStepRateValue_Record/>
                                        <EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                            <HRAssignmentID_Internal>300000015239345</HRAssignmentID_Internal>
                                            <PayGroupId>REPORT_BLANK</PayGroupId>
                                        </EEPSPayChange_Rec>
                                    </EEPSPayChange_Assignment>
                                </EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data>
                            </EEPSPayChange_Employment>
                        </EEPSPayChange>
                        <EEPSLocation>
                            <EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                                <EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                                    <EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                        <EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                            <PersonType_Internal>Apprenticeship</PersonType_Internal>
                                        </EEPSLocation_AssgnRecord>
                                    </EEPSLocation_AssgnDataGroup>
                                </EEPSLocation_TermsRecord>
                            </EEPSLocation_TermsDataGroup>
                        </EEPSLocation>
                        <EEBankDetail/>
                        <EEPaymentElement/>
                    </InterfaceData>
                </PayrollInterface>
            </FILE_FRAGMENT>
        </G_2>
    </G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <company>
            <Data>
                <Payroll>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="//InterfaceData" group-by="OBJECT_ACTION_ID">

                        <!-- Employee -->
                        <Employee>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()//EmployeeBasic">
                                <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="CGIelementToAttribute">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="myVarElementName" select="name(.)"/>
                                        <xsl:with-param name="myVarElementValue" select="current()"
                                        />
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>

                            <xsl:call-template name="CGIelementToAttribute">
                                <xsl:with-param name="myVarElementName" select="'PayGroup'"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="myVarElementValue" select="EEPSPayChange/EEPSPayChange_Employment[last()]/EEPSPayChange_Assignment_Data[1]/EEPSPayChange_Assignment[1]/EEPSPayChange_Rec[1]/PayGroupId[1]/text()"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>

                        </Employee>

                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </Payroll>
            </Data>
        </company>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="CGIelementToAttribute">
        <xsl:param name="myVarElementName"/>
        <xsl:param name="myVarElementValue"/>

        <!-- if the element value contains 'BLANK' or the element name ends with 'Internal' it will not be output -->
        <xsl:if
            test="not(contains('|BLANK|', concat('|', $myVarElementValue, '|'))) and not(ends-with(name(), 'Internal')) and not(contains('|Salary|', concat('|', $myVarElementName, '|')))">
            <xsl:choose>

                <!-- empty element -->
                <xsl:when test="$myVarElementValue = ''">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{$myVarElementName}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>

                <!-- output 'REPORT BLANK' as the attribute value -->
                <xsl:when test="(contains('|REPORT_BLANK|', concat('|', $myVarElementValue, '|')))">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{$myVarElementName}">
                        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="current()"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'REPORT_BLANK'"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>

                <!-- format date -->
                <xsl:when test="contains($myVarElementName, 'Date')">
                    <xsl:call-template name="formatDate">
                        <xsl:with-param name="myVarDateString" select="$myVarElementValue"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="myVarDateName" select="$myVarElementName"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>

                <!-- no transformation -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="{$myVarElementName}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$myVarElementValue"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>

            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="formatDate">

        <!-- CGIformatDate: converts dateto CGI format from CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss:mm[Z] to dd/mm/ccyy -->
        <xsl:param name="myVarDateString"/>
        <xsl:param name="myVarDateName"/>

        <xsl:attribute name="{$myVarDateName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($myVarDateString, 9, 2), '/', substring($myVarDateString, 6, 2), '/', substring($myVarDateString, 1, 4))"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="by"/>
        <xsl:variable name="str1">
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="str2">
            <!-- 2nd... clean up -->
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$str1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="str3">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when
                    test="substring($str2, string-length($str2) - string-length($by), string-length($str2)) = concat($by, ' ')">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="substring($str2, 1, string-length($str2) - string-length($by) - 1)"
                    />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$str2"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring($str3, 1, string-length($by) + 1) = concat($by, ' ')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($str3, concat($by, ' '))"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$str3"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace"/>
        <xsl:param name="by"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $replace)"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $replace)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <Data>
        <Payroll>
            <Employee EmployeeNo="50120" PayGroup="06"></Employee>
            <Employee EmployeeNo="50061" Status="TOBEDERIVED" PensElig="Y" PayGroup="08"></Employee>
            <Employee EmployeeNo="41356" EffectiveDate="04/10/2017" PensElig="Y"
                PayGroup="&#xA;                        18511&#xA;                        &#xA;                            &#xA;                                &#xA;                                    41356&#xA;                                    2017-10-04T00:00:00.000Z&#xA;                                    Y&#xA;                                &#xA;                                &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                            300000015238875&#xA;                                            &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                &#xA;                                &#xA;                                &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                            &#xA;                                            &#xA;                                            &#xA;                                            &#xA;                                            300000015238875&#xA;                                        &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                &#xA;                            &#xA;                        &#xA;                        &#xA;                            &#xA;                                &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                            300000015239345&#xA;                                        &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                &#xA;                            &#xA;                        &#xA;                        &#xA;                            &#xA;                                &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                            300000015239345&#xA;                                            &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                &#xA;                            &#xA;                        &#xA;                        &#xA;                            &#xA;                                &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                        &#xA;                                            Apprenticeship&#xA;                                        &#xA;                                    &#xA;                                &#xA;                            &#xA;                        &#xA;                        &#xA;                        &#xA;                   "
            ></Employee>
        </Payroll>
    </Data>
</company>
```

Comment: This is a result of calling `CGIelementToAttribute` with value `'REPORT_BLANK'`... You have to debug your `string-replace-all` function

Comment: I am completely new, what is the best way to debug? I have oxygen XML developer, is there a good link/video I can follow for debugging XSL?

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output You can make a simplest xml and start removing in your xslt not relevant parts till you get only the part that is problematic and - then you fix it and merge back into the original xslt

Comment: Looks like the `select="current()"` inside the `<xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">` does not bring you what you expect... You have to explain what this call to string-replace-all was intended to do

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is all `text()` descendants of `InterfaceData` are being output in your attribute. This includes whitespace and newlines.

If you add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` you'll see that the the hex references for newlines, along with the spaces, are removed. However, the value still appears to be incorrect.

I think this is because you're using `current()` in your call to template `string-replace-all` in the template named `CGIelementToAttribute`.

Try changing this:

```
<!-- output 'REPORT BLANK' as the attribute value -->
<xsl:when test="(contains('|REPORT_BLANK|', concat('|', $myVarElementValue, '|')))">
  <xsl:attribute name="{$myVarElementName}">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="current()"/>             <!-- THIS LINE -->
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'REPORT_BLANK'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

to this:

```
<!-- output 'REPORT BLANK' as the attribute value -->
<xsl:when test="(contains('|REPORT_BLANK|', concat('|', $myVarElementValue, '|')))">
  <xsl:attribute name="{$myVarElementName}">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$myVarElementValue"/>    <!-- THIS LINE -->
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'REPORT_BLANK'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

You might also need to replace:

```
<xsl:with-param name="by" select="''"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:with-param name="by" select="'REPORT BLANK'"/>
```

otherwise your attribute value will be blank. This is based on the comment before the `xsl:when`. (`<!-- output 'REPORT BLANK' as the attribute value -->`)

Also, if you're really using an XSLT 2.0 processor, why not just use the [`replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-replace) function instead of a named template?